# Zencart CSS and images not loading

Tags: css, permissions, content-management-system, http-status-code-404, zen-cart

I just upgraded my store from zencart 1.3.8 to 1.5.0

I installed newer version (1.5.0) and then imported my old database (1.3.8). Products are showing as they should be.

My issues are:

- no images are being shown for products
- no CSS is being loaded
- I can not access admin account..
- store url is [this](http://onlinesafetydepot.com/)
- i have turned of htaccess files for admin and store catalogue,
  firebug says error 404 for not loading images and CSS, I have checked
  that everything exists.

What should I do now? Any guidelines?

**UPDATE**

Error log shows entries like

> [client x.x.x.my ip] (13)Permission denied:
>   /home/besafe/public_html/images/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to
>   check htaccess file, ensure it is readable, referer:
>   http://onlinesafetydepot.com/images/abel-8805-firefighter.jpg

Comment: share some info... it seems to me that have problem with paths

Comment: what information needs to be shared? tell me..I will provde it all

Comment: I checked my error log via cpanel and error log is given above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heck....

it was the permission issue of specific files and folders...

two configuration files are used in zencart, after upgrade, they need permissions to be changed to 644 or 444 . In my case 644 works..

also, The folders needed to set the permissions of 755. in my case, `images, store_include and admin_include` needed 755 chmod permission..